# Why is Vue serving some basic website instead of the app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to create a simple vueapp.

I ran

```
vue create test
```

I cd'ed into `test`
and run `npm run serve`

on `localhost:8080`

I get the following the browser

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

curl gives me

```
$ curl localhost:8080 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>test</title>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

have

```
$ vue --version  
@vue/cli 4.5.9
```

Which setting might be wrong. I checked my `~/.profile` file which includes

```
PATH="$HOME/.node_modules/bin:$PATH"
export npm_config_prefix=~/.node_modules
```

I checked the `src` directory but I there is no html file with `it works`. What does

> We're sorry but test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.

mean

```
package.json

----------------
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The page is supposed the basic vuejs test app instead of `it works` as mentioned in the post

Comment: Could you please post the entire structure of your project?

Comment: It is the default structure when using `vue create <name>`

Comment: FWIW, when I install Vue and use `vue create test` with defaults, then `cd test`, and `npm run serve`, loading `http://localhost:8080` gives me a page with a lot more than "It works," so this is something specific to your system you'll have to debug at that end I'm afraid. (I also don't see how you can get completely different HTML in your browser than from `curl`. I don't. In both cases I get what you've shown as the output of `curl`.) Good luck with it!

Comment: Any hints on where to debug this? I thought it might my system. I reset the npm settings. but nothing else.

Comment: Could you list the exact steps you use to create your project?

Comment: Some super heavy caching in your browser from a previous project on the same port‽